# cron job on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I need create a schedule job, i am using Google App engine.
The requirement is the cron job will be execute each 10 minutes like this
0,10,20,30,40,50,60 in each hour.
I read the documentation from Google site at : [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/cronref#schedule_format][1]

This is my config :

```
schedule: every 10 minutes from 00:00 to 23:50
```

Is it correct with the requirment ?

Comment: Yes, correct.  But, if you are covering the entire day, just `schedule: every 10 minutes`

Comment: @GAEfan - this should be an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct.  But, if you are covering the entire day, just:

```
schedule: every 10 minutes
```